# R - basic function - Rank of a vector within a matrix, by observation

Tags: r, function, ranking, rank

I would like to perform the rank of a column vector within a matrix.

I have the following matrix "data"

`> data <- matrix (c(12,43,15,17,15,23,4,50,43,6,91,8), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)`

With names and date it should look like this

```
Date  Obs     y1   y2   y3
```

```
2014   1      12   15   43 
2014   2      43   23   6
2013   1      15   4    91
2013   2      17   50   8
```

output should be the rank of a variable against other variables, for each unique observation (date*Obs)

```
Date  Obs        formula(y1)  formula(y2)  formula(y3)
```

```
2014   1         3            2            1
2014   2         1            2            3
2013   1         2            3            1
2013   2         2            1            3
```

EDIT : Thanks to @Tim Hoolihan and user20650, for a simple matrix is :
`t(apply(data, 1, function(x) rank(-x)))`

Thank you for the help - from a lost noob.

Comment: It is not clear about the criteria for calculating the `rank`

Comment: As a side note: this: `1:length(data[,1])` will break when `data` is empty or whenever you graduate from "noob" to dplyr-user. Prefer: `seq_len(nrow(data))`

Comment: Chrischeese, can you explain in words how you want to rank the variables please

Comment: just edited, apologies for the confusion - hope clarity has increased...

Comment: do you want `t(apply(-dat, 1, rank))` (as it seems Date*Obs is unique)

Comment: Yes Date*Obs  is unique. thanks for the advice

Comment: You might also want to look into `matrixStats` package, i.e. `rowRanks(-data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use apply to iterate over the rows and rank them:

```
> data <- matrix (c(12,43,15,17,15,23,4,50,43,6,91,8), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
> t(apply(data, 1, function(x) rank(-x)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    1
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    2    3    1
[4,]    2    1    3
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, the result intended is :  `t(apply(data, 1, function(x) rank(-x)))`. cheers.

Comment: @Chrischeese thanks, I didn't realize you were ranking by row, not column. I updated my example. Please mark as the answer since it solves your problem.